# JSF Viewscope bean dies too early because of multipart

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x, mojarra

i have a form that is a multipart form and a ViewScoped Backing Bean.

When i submit the multipart form the to the same page the Backing Bean gets recreated..

I expected that the bean would still be there as it would be on a "normal" form.

Here is some sample Code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:commandButton value="Preview2" ajax="false" />
    <p:inputText id="photolink" size="60" value="#{test.photolink}" />
</h:form>
```

The inputText gets cleared.

When i use this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Preview2" ajax="false" />
    <p:inputText id="photolink" size="60" value="#{test.photolink}" />
</h:form>
```

The input text stays as it should...

**Is there a way to fix this behaviour ?**

Edit: This is the whole xhtml that doesnt work:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

<h:form id="editArticle" enctype="multipart/form-data" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
    <p:inputText id="title" value="#{test.photolink}" />
    <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="submit" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>atlas</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

My mojarra version:

**Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401)**

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. What Mojarra and PrimeFaces version?

Comment: I use primefaces 3.5 and the default mojarra that ships with jboss 7.1

Here comes the really interesting part, i have a multipart form in my project (working with a viewscope bean) that behaves like i want now i am going to investige why it works there!

Comment: The cause is at least not visible in the code provided so far. Are you sure that you didn't oversimplify it too much? Perhaps you're somewhere else in the very same view binding properties of the view scoped bean to a JSTL tag attribute or the `binding` attribute of a JSF component? We of course assume that the given code reproduces exactly the desired problem when being placed stragiht in `<h:body>` of a completely blank template.

Comment: Wow, i found the reason! When i call the page through prettyfaces everything works as expected ! When call the page through /faces/test.xhtml i doesnt ! Somehow prettyfaces fixed my problem (the first time it wasn't the reason of one..)

Comment: I posted my code that produces the error. I don't think i oversimplified it..

Comment: I know also added the web.xml and my mojarra version

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem using the exact Mojarra+PrimeFaces+JBoss configuration as you mentioned. You didn't mention anywhere that you're using PrettyFaces which can theoretically indeed very good be the whole cause of this problem. When posting a question, always make absolutely sure that one can reproduce your problem starting with a **completely blank** project based on the information provided so far in the question. When unsure due to lack of in depth knowledge of the stuff used, always create one yourself.

Comment: By the way, the `<form acceptCharset>` is ignored in sane browsers and severely broken in MSIE browsers. Just don't use it.

Comment: I found my bug and posted the solution below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my bug, and nobody could find it since my question was incomplete...

My problem was that i mixed JSF scopes and the CDI @Named annotation.

So my bean looked like this:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
```

Instead of

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

That resulted in very strange behaviour as described in this Thread..

Answer (score 0):

I found a workarround that is good enough for me even though i don't understand it...

The solution is to call the page through a prettyfaces url and not via `/faces/something.xhtml`

A simple prettyfaces rule like:

```
  <url-mapping id="test2"> 
      <pattern value="/test2"/> 
      <view-id value="/faces/test2.xhtml" />
  </url-mapping>
```

fixed everything for me !

I Hope someone can explain why this is happening and why prettytime fixed this odd behaviour..